# Why network call fails after the internet comes back in react native android application?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am working with react native Android application. I am calling API using fetch and axios lib. There is some issue while the internet goes down and comes back. The API call gets failed but the internet is there.
This how I'm doing the fetch call.

```
fetch(Url,{
    timeout: config.apiFetchTimeOut,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      tenantName: this.props.config.tenantName,
      'tekion-api-token': this.props.config.access_token,
      dealerId: this.props.config.dealerId,
      clientID: 'console',
    }},)
    .then(response => {
        console.log("response",response)
        NativeModules.NativeOTTModule.logger('Ping Api Response=> '+JSON.stringify(response));
        let apiSuccess = JSON.parse(response._bodyInit).meta.code;
        if(apiSuccess===200){
          if(context.state.showIcon){
            context.setState({showIcon:false});
            context.stopRebootTimer();
          }
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("ping error",error)  
    })
```

Comment: I see no reference to axios.

Comment: i am using both axios and fetch . I have posted only the fetch api code

Comment: What's your error when the call fails?

Comment: There is no error as the fetch call runs infinitely. I have given a timeout. for 15 sec.